# Can laravel schema builder create CHAR column?

Tags: database-design, char, schema, laravel, builder

Sorry for the annoying question, but I didn't find the way to create a table with a CHAR column. I want CHAR, not VARCHAR!

In the documentation, they don't write anything about CHAR type columns:
http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema

What if I want a CHAR(6) type column where only 6 char long strings are allowed, must I create a varchar column and forbid in the model to be shorter or longer than 6 char?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say [the laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/schema) doesn't support a CHAR datatype.  That's all there is to it.

But that is probably beside the point.  CHAR(6) does not enforce a rule that all values must be six characters long.  What it does is right-pad any input to six characters.  So we can enter `'A'` and the CHAR column will store `'A     '`.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Then my conjecture was right :D. I create those min max rules anyway, but i wasnt sure about using varchar for this, but its ok. Thank you for the answer.